# How to remove whitespaces from generated HTML?

Tags: php, html

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
<?php
    function global_header($page)
    {
        echo "
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang='en'>
        <head>
            <meta charset='utf-8' />
            <title>" . $page . "</title>
            <meta name='description' content='BTI320 Assignment 2' />
        </head>
            <body>
        ";
    }
?>
<?php
    function global_footer()
    {
        echo "
            </body>
        </html>
        ";
    }
?>
```

When I view my page source in chrome/FF I get the following source:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Add</title>
        <meta name='description' content='BTI320 Assignment 2' />
    </head>
        <body>

        </body>
    </html>
```

It's indented by about 3 tabs. Is there a PHP strip function or something that can align it properly? I don't like my entire pages HTML being messed up.

My expected output is to not be indented.

Comment: What is your expected output ??

Comment: Do what everyone else does, remove the tabs and newlines to conserve bytes, and don't mind how it looks, as I'm assuming you don't spend all day looking at the code in "view source" in your browser.

Comment: No but it rubs me the wrong way lol.

Comment: If you like well formatted output, this is most easily done by using an output buffer that re-formats the HTML before outputting it to the browser, for example with the help of *Tidy* or *DOMDocument* which have function for proper HTML indentation. *Tidy* even allows you to specify a maximum line-length like 78 characters.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out `tidy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting indented outputs is that you are echoing them like that...
Simply remove the indentaions from the echo statements to get rid of them

```
<?php
    function global_header($page)
    {
        echo "
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>" . $page . "</title>
<meta name='description' content='BTI320 Assignment 2' />
</head>
<body>";
    }
?>
<?php
    function global_footer()
    {
        echo "
</body>
</html>";
    }
?>
```

This makes your php harder to follow fut the output will be as you requested

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a template engine. Direct output of HTML strings is considered bad practice.

If you don't want to use third-party template engines, you can anyway benefit from some simplified templating like this:

**`page.tpl` template file**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>

<body>

{{body}}

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```php
// Loading HTML code that does not contain any undesired whitespace.
$code = file_get_contents('page.tpl');

// Replacing template variables with their values.
$code = str_replace(
    array(
        '{{title}}',
        '{{body}}'
    ),
    array(
        'Example title',
        'Page body'
    ),
    $code
);

// Outputting resulting HTML code.
echo $code;
```

Comment: PHP *is* a templating engine, that's why you have those <?php ?> tags.

Comment: @eveo I've added an example of simplified templating that is as easy to use as your "pure-PHP" HTML output is.

Comment: As Esailija notes, PHP basically is a templating engine. Maybe in Ruby or Python, it's considered bad practice to not use one... and it is... but I disagree that using one for PHP is widely considered best practice.